# setchecked( false) of the switch doesn't work

Tags: android

I have written a app.In that I'm having 2 tab in my activity.In 1st tab having 2 switches.when i click on 1st tab I need to off the switch if anyone is on.I have tried setchecked(false) but it is not working.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, container, false);

    Switch Default = (Switch)view.findViewById(R.id.Default);
    Switch FMR = (Switch)view.findViewById(R.id.FMR);
        if(Default.isChecked()){
        Default.setChecked(false);  
        }
                if(FMR.isChecked()){
        FMR.setChecked(false);  
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this out

```
myTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
if(TAB_1_TAG.equals(tabId)) { //off the required switch
   Default.setChecked(false); 
   FMR.setChecked(false); 
}
if(TAB_2_TAG.equals(tabId)) {
   //off the required switch
}
}});
```

Comment: I am using tabs in action bar.so there is no tabhost.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.

```
 Default.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (isChecked) {
                           Default.setChecked(false);  
                    } 
                    }
                }
            });
```

HTH. For more Read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html)

if you want to set the switch to `OFF` for the first time, Then remove the `if` in your code.

```
Switch Default = (Switch)view.findViewById(R.id.Default);
Switch FMR = (Switch)view.findViewById(R.id.FMR);
Default.setChecked(false);  
FMR.setChecked(false);
```

Comment: I think this will check only when I click on the switch.I need to off the switch with out clicking switch